# HashMap : Dealing with Managed objects C++

Tags: c++-cli, hashtable

I guess it's kind of a stupid question but here is my problem :

I want to have a `hash_map<int, Object^>` as an attribute of my object `BigObject`, which is written in managed C++.

So I have to declare a pointer, `hash_map<int, Object^>* hash` because I cannot declare explicitely native object in managed code.

How can I insert an object ? the `hash_map[]` won't work with a pointer, and I cannot make insert work (I cannot use a `std::pair<int, Object^>` because Object is managed...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your hashmap as `hash_map<int, gcroot<Object^> >`. You will need to `#include <vcclr.h>`

See also [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/481fa11f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

edit: added code sample

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <hash_map>

using namespace std;
using namespace stdext;
using namespace System;

int main()
{
  hash_map<int, gcroot<Object^> > hash;

  hash.insert( make_pair<int, gcroot<Object^> >( 5,
                 gcnew String("hello world") ) );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in .NET, why not use one of the .NET collections?  They are directly usable in C++/CLI, and can also be shared with other .NET languages, which a `std::hash_map` cannot.  And they play nicely with the garbage collector.

.NET provides several hashtable implementations, including ['System.Collections.HashTable'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) and [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

In your case, a `Dictionary<int, Object^>^` would be appropriate.

Comment: I wanted to use a multimap in fact. A dictionnary can only direct one key to one value right?

Comment: in that scenario I usually use a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash_map <double,gcroot<siteNEVObjectdic^>> d;
d.insert(make_pair<double,gcroot<siteNEVObjectdic^>>(PN2,gcnew siteNEVObjectdic(Lat1,Long1,Lat2,Long2,Lat3,Long3)));
```

this worked as a charm.